# Changing WAV Audio File Number of frames format for Pytorch

Tags: python, audio, pytorch, audio-processing

I am trying to write a model for audio classification, for that I am using `torchaudio.datasets.SPEECHCOMMANDS` dataset. I have trained the model but on custom sounds for prediction and evaluation, I am having issues with converting them to same format as used by my model.
Following is `torchaudio.info` command and result of my dataset audio file:

```
metadata = torchaudio.info("./data/SpeechCommands/speech_commands_v0.02/yes/00f0204f_nohash_0.wav")
print("Origional  :", metadata)
```

Result:

```
Origional  : AudioMetaData(sample_rate=16000, num_frames=16000, num_channels=1, bits_per_sample=16, encoding=PCM_S)
```

I am using `pydub` to apply transformation to my data. Following is the code I have used:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_wav("/content/yes.wav") # yes.wav is my recorded file
sound = sound.set_channels(1)
sound = sound.set_frame_rate(16000)
sound.export("/content/yes_mono.wav", format="wav")
```

Still after these transformation, my custom audio file's format is different to the one in dataset.

```
metadata = torchaudio.info("/content/yes_mono.wav")
print("Custom Mono:", metadata)
#Result: Custom Mono: AudioMetaData(sample_rate=16000, num_frames=36864, num_channels=1, bits_per_sample=16, encoding=PCM_S)
```

Here `num_frames` are different and I have been unable to find a way to solve this. Please suggest a solution or highlight issue in my understanding.

Comment: I know nothing about pytorch however standard audio sample-rate is 44100 not 16000 ... this measure indicates number of samples taken per second ... I suggest you confirm your source wav file  sample rate ...  `ffprobe  /your/file/path/audio.wav` will display sample rate of the given file